# VBA: Multiple Userforms Referencing Same Code

Tags: excel, vba, label, userform, caption

I have a VBA code that takes user inputs (criteria) via a userform, creates a list of items that meet said criteria, and randomly outputs one of the list items via message box.

I want to create a second userform that will open after the above code completes, and have the userform display the random output.

I have a few questions regarding how this can be done.

1. I want to the second userform to contain a label, whose caption will reflect the random output.
2. I want the second userform to allow the user to re-execute the original code (ie. to change the random result)

Anyone have experience with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a Property procedure in the second form to get the random value.

As an example in a new blank workbook:
Insert a new module and paste in the code below.  This code represents your code which outputs a random result.

```
Public Function RandomNumber() As Double

    RandomNumber = Rnd(10)

End Function
```

Create a new userform (UserForm2), add a command button (CommandButton1) and a label (Label1).    Add the below code to this form.  I've put four procedures in there.  MyProp sets the value of **ThePassedNumber**, **UpdateLabel1** updates the value shown in the label, **UserForm_Initialize** executes when the form loads, **CommandButton1_Click** executes when you click the button.

```
Private ThePassedNumber As Double

Property Let MyProp(TheNumber As Double)
    ThePassedNumber = TheNumber
    UpdateLabel1
End Property


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    ThePassedNumber = RandomNumber
    UpdateLabel1

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    UpdateLabel1

End Sub

Private Sub UpdateLabel1()

    Me.Label1.Caption = ThePassedNumber

End Sub
```

Add a second form (UserForm1) and add a command button (CommandButton1) and place this code within the form.
It will create a new instance of the userform, pass a random value to it and then display the form.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim frm2 As UserForm2

    Set frm2 = New UserForm2
    frm2.MyProp = RandomNumber
    frm2.Show

End Sub
```

Now you just need to rewrite the RandomNumber function to return your list item rather than a number.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed. It took a lot of extra tinkering, but now my code works like a dream.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you just want to use an endless loop that the user breaks when canceled.
Something like this:

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim myRandOutput As Single
    Do
        myRandOutput = myRand()
    Loop While MsgBox(myRandOutput, vbRetryCancel) = vbRetry
End Sub

Function myRand() As Single
    myRand = Rnd()
End Function
```